# TFBS search with TFBSTools and a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am currently looking for TFBS motifs in DNA. The original code I wrote to look for 10 different transcription factor motifs worked beautifully. But now I want to search for more than 100 motifs. Therefore I want to use loops so that I dont have to type in all the motif names manually (and can easily change my list if my interests change). But when I do this my code no longer works. I can print the result of the loops and it looks like the list contains all the correct information, but when I then use this list to compare with my DNA the list seems to only remember the last item of the list.

Here is my original code that works:

```
initializeJASPARDB("jaspar.sqlite", version="2014")
MA0018.2 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0018.2")
MA0024.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0024.1")
MA0062.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0062.1")
MA0099.2 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0099.2")
MA0112.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0112.1")
MA0153.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0153.1")
MA0156.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0156.1")
MA0157.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0157.1")
MA0158.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0158.1")
MA0259.1 <- getMatrixByID(db, ID="MA0259.1")

pwm1 <- toPWM(MA0018.2)
pwm2 <- toPWM(MA0024.1)
pwm3 <- toPWM(MA0062.1)
pwm4 <- toPWM(MA0099.2)
pwm5 <- toPWM(MA0112.1)
pwm6 <- toPWM(MA0153.1)
pwm7 <- toPWM(MA0156.1)
pwm8 <- toPWM(MA0157.1)
pwm9 <- toPWM(MA0158.1)
pwm10 <- toPWM(MA0259.1)

pwmList <- PWMatrixList(pwm1=pwm1, pwm2=pwm2, pwm3=pwm3, pwm4=pwm4, pwm5=pwm5, pwm6=pwm6, pwm7=pwm7, pwm8=pwm8, pwm9=pwm9, pwm10=pwm10)

seq3 <- readDNAStringSet(file = "sequences/HBV/HBV_genotypeEplusFplusGplusHplusRF.fasta")

sitesetList <- searchSeq(pwmList, seq3, min.score="90%")

as(sitesetList, "data.frame")
as(sitesetList, "DataFrame")
as(sitesetList, "GRanges")
#writeGFF3(sitesetList)
Viruses_TFBS <- writeGFF2(sitesetList)

write.csv(Viruses_TFBS, file = "analysis_HBV/HBV_combmanually_10TFBS.csv")

head(Viruses_TFBS, 5)
```

Here is my new code with the loop:

```
TFBS_motifs <- read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv")
seqHSV <- readDNAStringSet(file = "sequences/HSV1.fasta")

# for loop objects
TFBS_matrices <- list()
pwms <- list()
TFBS_ID <- TFBS_motifs$ID

for (i in 1:nrow(TFBS_motifs)) {
  
 pwms[[i]] <- toPWM(TFBS_matrices[[i]] <- getMatrixByID(db, ID = TFBS_ID[[i]]))
  
}
 #print(pwms)

pwmList <- PWMatrixList(pwms[[i]])

sitesetList <- searchSeq(pwmList, seqHSV, min.score="90%")


as(sitesetList, "data.frame")
as(sitesetList, "DataFrame")
as(sitesetList, "GRanges")
#writeGFF3(sitesetList)
HSV_TFBS <- writeGFF2(sitesetList)

write.csv(HSV_TFBS, file = "analysis_HBV/HSV_test.csv")
```

Thank you all so much for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to run this in a loop; most of these commands can deal with lists. Try something like this:

```r
library(TFBSTools)
library(JASPAR2018) # or use 2014 version if you prefer
library(Biostrings)
db <- file.path(system.file("extdata", package="JASPAR2018"), "JASPAR2018.sqlite")

# provide your motifs here or read in from file
mymotifs <- c("MA0018.2", "MA0024.1", "MA0062.1", "MA0099.2") 
PFMatrixList <- getMatrixByID(db, ID=mymotifs)

# provide your genome fasta file here
HSV1 <- readDNAStringSet("ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/ena/wgs/public/fkj/FKJZ01.fasta.gz") 
sitesetList <- searchSeq(toPWM(PFMatrixList), HSV1, min.score="90%")

# generate GRangesList (and unlist if you prefer a single GRanges object)
unlist(as(sitesetList, "GRangesList"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This looks promising. Sadly, I get the following error message: "Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, id, value = .get_Matrix_by_int_id(x, int_id, : no such index at level 1" when I execute "PFMatrixList <- getMatrixByID(db, ID=mymotifs)" from a list. This is what my code currently looks like: ```{r} mymotifs <- read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv" PFMatrixList <- getMatrixByID(db, ID=mymotifs)) ```. I am very sorry - I am fairly new to R... Is there a problem with my list? 
PFMatrixList <- getMatrixByID(db, ID=mymotifs)

Comment: You need to pass a character vector of matrix motifs to `getMatrix` (just as in the reproducible example I provided), not a data.frame, which I suspect your `mymotifs` would be. Not knowing the structure of your file I can only suspect that the first column in your list is likely the vector of motifs that you want to pass to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly. My csv file has two columns, first one being the motifs, second one being the name of the transcription factors. When I read my csv as character vector for column 1 (mymotifs <- as.character(read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv")$V1) ) the code runs a bit further until I get an error message: Error in do.call(SiteSetList, unlist(lapply(ans_list, as, "list"))) : second argument must be a list

Comment: This is not clear without a reproducible example. Does my reproducible example work for you? Make sure the classes of the data match what works using my reproducible example. Check input requirements of the functions you use (e.g. `?getMatrixByID` should show you the details for that function). PFMatrixList should be a `PFMatrixList`, mymotifs a character vector, db should point to an sqlite database and SiteSetList should be a `SiteSetList` object.

Comment: yes, your example works perfectly fine. I am currently only using your code. I have only changed the line "mymotifs <- as.character(read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv")$V1)" to read the first column of my csv file as a character vector. Then the code runs until "sitesetList <-...", stops again and gives me the error "Error in do.call(SiteSetList, unlist(lapply(ans_list, as, "list"))) : second argument must be a list"

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code "mymotifs <- as.character(read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv")$V1)" ??? I am sorry, but I really cant get this to work... I have tried wrapping various parts of code into "list()" to solve my error message, but this only gives me other error messages... So I am clueless what the problem is, since your example works flawless...

Comment: After you loaded `mymotifs` with the above command, how does the object `mymotifs` look like? You could paste the output of `dput(mymotifs)` here, and/or examine it by looking at the output of `str(mymotifs)`. It should be a character vector with IDs from the database.

Comment: Brillant. Thank you so much. This was helpful. With dput(mymotifs) I learned that my character vector is actually empty, because $V1 was the wrong column. My csv-file has a header which I can call on. So the correct line of code now is "mymotifs <- read.csv("TFBS_motifs_test.csv")$ID". Thank you everyone for your help!